# TeamSpeak 3 Tray Icon

Tags: 15.10, teamspeak, qsystemtrayicon

I have TeamSpeak 3 installed but it doesn't show a tray icon, and I'd like it to. I cannot find anything regarding this other than an [outdated post on howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/68119/how-to-bring-app-icons-back-into-unitys-system-tray/).

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10. If you need me to provide any other information, please just ask!